# Session redirect url not applying after facebook callback laravel

Tags: laravel, facebook, session

I have the following `session data` which gets set just prior to logging in via `facebook`

```
session(['redirecturl'=>'someurl']);
```

Then in my facebook callback code, i have:

```
public function callback($provider)
{
    $getInfo = Socialite::driver($provider)->user(); 
    $user = $this->createUser($getInfo,$provider); 
    auth()->login($user);
    return redirect()->to(session('redirect_url'));
}
```

The issue is, the value of `session('redirect_url')` is `null` at the callback area.

What can I do to resolve this issue? It seems like facebook is trashing the `session data`. If i can even get a reload of the calling page thatd be useful.

Comment: Does `session('redirect_url')` give you `null` just after you set `session(['redirecturl'=>'someurl']);`?

Comment: nevermind i figured it out i used the incorrect key

Comment: Ahh!! I missed that too :)